# How to print a character multiline in R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, character

I have a medium length `character` in R `markdown`. The output looks good / readable in the RStudio preview but is a one liner in `html` output after the code chunk requiring scrolling to the right.

````
---
title: "Make A Long Character Readable in R"
output: html_document
---

# Wikipedia

```{r}
library(wikifacts)
R_EN <- wiki_define('R (programming language)')
R_EN
```
````

Preview is fine:

[image]

Whereas html output is not readable:

[image]

What is the best way to get a readable output?

Answer (score 0):

There's a attribute that you can include on each chunk to limit the output's width:

```
options(width = 80)
library(wikifacts)
R_EN <- wiki_define('R (programming language)')
R_EN
```

**Edit**: if this don't work, you can try, alternatively, a css code for the HTML:

````
```{css, echo=F}
pre code {
   white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```{r}
#options(width = 40)
library(wikifacts)
R_EN <- wiki_define('R (programming language)')
R_EN
```
````

Which results in this output when I run the chunk:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiGsZ.png)

Comment: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/text-width.html says "The R global option width can be used to control the width of printed text output from some R functions, ..." `options(width = 80)` works for `matrix` für not for the `R_EN`